# Running Curl command in python

Tags: python, curl, cgi

I'm running the following curl command in CGI script in python using os.system call as below:

```
os.system('curl -u username:password -X PUT example.com/data/data1.txt -T /diskless/desktop/file.txt\r\n')
```

Getting the below error when I run the CGI script:

> '!rl: Can't open '/diskless/desktop/file.txt')  curl: try 'curl
>   --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: do you specifically require `curl` or can you not use other python libraries to handle `http` requests for you (like `python requests` for example)

Comment: I want to upload a file from my local directory to  the http path that I specify. This will be executed in python CGI. Can you give me a sample code

Comment: look at the error - `Can't open '/diskless/desktop/file.txt'`. do you have permissions on the file you are trying to upload?

Comment: Yes, I have. It's the problem with '\r\n' at the end of the command. This '\r\n' is required if you are executing it in a CGI script; otherwise you would get a malformed header error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use `subprocess`

```
import subprocess
command = 'curl -u username:password -X PUT example.com/data/data1.txt -T /diskless/desktop/file.txt\r\n'
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

Comment: @lliyan Markov- Any idea on why os.systme() is getting failed if I use '\r\n' at the end of the command. Also, your subprocess.POPEN is getting the following error : p = subprocess.POPEN(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'POPEN'

Comment: Sorry, lliyan. There's no error now. But, I don;t see file getting uploaded.

Comment: do you actually need to have `\r\n` at the end of that command?

Comment: If we are executing curl command in CGI script using os.system, it's required, otherwise you would get a malformed header error.

Comment: try that: `command = curl -X POST -d @/diskless/desktop/file.txt http://username:password@example.com/uploadlink/`

Comment: @lliyan, It's working fine using subprocess.Popen(). Thanks for that. If we want to exexute two shell commands how to execute it. subprocess.Popen(cmd1) and subprocess(cmd2) is not working. Secondly, any idea why os.system() is failing if I use \r\n at the end.

Comment: I am happy this helped you! Well you can run the above snippet twice passing different commands each time or you can use `linux pipes` and build one command. It depends what you are trying to do. I am not sure why `os.system` didn't like `\r\n` but generally you don't call `shell` from `python` using that method.

Comment: If I run p= subprocess.call(cmd1,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE) (out1,err1) = p.communicate() q = subprocess(cmd2,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE) (out2, err2) = q.communicate() I'm getting the following error: out2 undefined, err2 undefined, q = <subprocess.Popen object>, q.communicate = <bound method Popen.communicate of <subprocess.Popen object>> 

<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable 
      args = ("'instancemethod' object is not iterable",) 
     message = "'instancemethod' object is not iterable"